# Propriedade RowSource VBA - Data em formato de número

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Olá, lancei uma combobox que extrai os dados da planilha e a coluna esta configurada como data.
Quando clico na cbb, aparecem as datas mas quando seleciono, retorna a data em forma de número.

```
linha = Sheets("Compras_e_Vendas").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row    
cbbdata.RowSource = "Compras_e_Vendas!F2:F" & linha
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar o seu problema, você deve sobre-escrever o método `Change` da `ComboBox`, colocando na formatação desejada dentro da sobreescrita, assim:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
  ComboBox1.Value = Format(ComboBox1.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
End Sub
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).